# Using the YouTube v3 Data API for .NET, how is it possible to get a refresh token?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, access-token, youtube-data-api

I need to be able to use a refresh token to be able to re-authenticate a token after the access token has expired. How can I do this using the C# v3 API? I've looked at the UserCredential class and AuthorizationCodeFlow class and nothing is jumping out at me.

I'm using the following code to authenticate it originally.

```
var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None);
if (result.Credential != null)
{
    var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                    ApplicationName = "YouTube Upload Tool"
                });
}
```

And this is my **AppFlowMetadata** class.

```
public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
{
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {

            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "ID",
                ClientSecret = "SECRET",
            },
            Scopes = new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            DataStore = new EFDataStore(-1) // A data store I implemented using Entity Framework 6.
        });

    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        return "test";

    }

    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }
}
```

If anyone can suggest anything, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it. [check my solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684334/oauth-2-google-api-refresh-token-is-null

Comment: Thank you for this question, even thought it does not solve my problem. I'm just glad that someone else thinks Google's OAuth 2.0 API docs are really shallow. They portray a "everything just works" idea, but as coders we know it is never the case! I need a solution for ASP.Net and nowhere in their MVC samples do they redirect the user...

Comment: Yup. Found the API to be very frustrating. The flow programming model they implemented seems to really only suit specific use cases, which is fine, but isn't clear enough in the documentation. I think offline access should be a commonly expected thing from an API, so documenting how to do this properly should definitely be there (disclaimer: I haven't looked in a while, so it may well be there now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not an answer, this is how I got around it. I had to create the GET request for authorisation (redirect your user to the url you get back and set your Controller Action to receive the callback specified in your Google Developer Console) and the PUT request for the Token (which I then stored using EF6) manually. I used `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to make these requests, which was quite straight forward. See [this link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#overview) for all the details I needed to get this working.

It was the only way I could set the `access_type` to "offline". If the .NET API does this, I'm still curious to find out how.

With the token data stored, I now use the API to validate and refresh the token when I need to. I actually did this in a server side console application rather than a MVC app (hence the EF token persistence).

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "ID",
        ClientSecret = "Secret"
    },
    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
    "12345",
    CancellationToken.None, 
    new EFDataStore(-1) // My own implementation of IDataStore
            );

    // This bit checks if the token is out of date, 
    // and refreshes the access token using the refresh token.
    if(credential.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
    {
        if (!await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No valid refresh token.");
        }
    }            

    var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "MY App"
    });
```

I hope this helps others.